# How can I rid a string of all leading and trailing non 'a-z' characters ONLY? Leaving anything sandwiched between 'a-z' characters alone?

Tags: c++

What I have here keeps giving me a segmentation fault.

I want to take in a string and remove only leading and trailing non 'a-z' characters while leaving anything that may be sandwiched in between alone. i.e.

> input = ....h...i....
>   output = h...i

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>


std::string frontCut(std::string someWord) {
    //std::string correctedWord;
    if (someWord[0] >= 'a' && someWord[0] <= 'z') {
        return someWord;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; someWord[i] < 'a' || someWord[i] > 'z'; i++) {

            someWord.erase(someWord[i], 1);
        }
    }
    return someWord;
}

std::string backCut(std::string someWord) {
    if (someWord.back() >= 'a' && someWord.back() <= 'z') {
        return someWord;
    }
    for (int i = someWord.length() - 1; someWord[i] < 'a' || someWord[i] > 'z'; i--) {
        someWord.pop_back();
    }
    return someWord;
}

int main() {
    std::string aWord = ".......hi......";
    frontCut(aWord);
    std::cout << aWord << '\n' << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The erase method will change the indexing, so your code in frontcut will not work as you thought

Comment: Do you know how to use iterators and some basic C++ library algorithms? This is trivial, by using iterators, and some basic algorithms, like `find_if`. Should only take seven or eight, or so, lines of code. Working this out in my head, just one call to `find_if`, and one basic `while` loop. That's it. Just forget everything that's done here, start from scratch, use iterators to trim off the unwanted leading and trailing parts, then construct a new `std::string`, from the iterator range. Mission accomplished. P.S. the reason for the segfault is because erase() doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What do return is there is no a-z character in the string?

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior in the `frontCut` loop if `i` is increased to be equal to or greater than the `size` of `someword`. And the `backCut` has the same issue when `i` is decremented from 0 to -1.

Comment: Look at the reference page for `std::find_first_of` and `std::find_first_not_of` for `std::string`. I'd use that to find the index, and `std::erase` to remove the offending characters (if any). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is presumably to find the first and last a-z character and then take the sub-string between them. Something like this (not tried & tested)

```
std::string shrink_non_alpha(std::string const&str)
{
    auto first = std::find_if(str.begin(),str.end(),std::lower);
    auto last = str.end()-1;
    while(first < last && !std::lower(last))
        --last;
    return {first,last+1};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string ip = "12jshdkasd..";
    std::cout << ip << std::endl;

    std::string pattern = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string::size_type startPos = ip.find_first_of(pattern);
    std::string::size_type endPos = ip.find_last_of(pattern);

    std::string op = ip.substr(startPos, (endPos - startPos + 1));
    std::cout << op << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I see many lines of code in the answers.

Please note. For this purpose, we have a dedicated function: `std::regex_replace`.

It will do exactly what you want in an one-liner. And, since such a dedicated function exists, you should use it.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    // Test data
    std::string test{ "...a....z...." };

    // Replace
    test = std::regex_replace(test, std::regex(R"((^[^\w]+)|([^\w]+$))"), "");

    // Show result;
    std::cout << test << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```